# Nested resources create_checklist for all users in commandline on has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-resources

Sorry if this has been asked already, but I can't find any questions similar.

Using rails 5.

I have a double-nested resource

```
resources :users do
    resources :checklists do
        resources :checklist_items do
            member do
                patch :completed
            end
        end
    end
end
```

And I have

**user.rb**

```
user has_one :checklist
```

**checklist.rb**

```
checklist belongs_to :user
```

And I know how to create a new checklist for one user in the commandline:

```
User.checklist.create
```

Now I want to create a new checklist for all the existing users in the database via the commandline. Sort of like this imaginary command:

```
User.all.checklist_create
```

so that every user gets a checklist. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, but maybe there is a shorter way to achieve it?

```
User.all.each do |user|
user.create_checklist
end
```

Comment: User.all.each{|u| u.create_checklist}

Answer (score 0):

Rails and Ruby are filled with lots of metaprogramming and I won't be surprise if a method like what you are suggesting actually exist. However, from a design perspective, I think that would be an overkill. Imagine if you had 10K+ users and you want to use that single command to create tickets for all 10k users? How about their fields for each ticket. 
So to solve your problem here are few options you can consider to have it your way.

Factory Girl

With factory girl, you have methods like `create_list`, `build list`, check out their documentation for more. From their names, they seem intuitive enough. These methods help you to create list of several objects and based on how you structure your factories, you can have what you desire in just one line.

Seed.rb

Rails provides a seed.rb file where you can add ruby script that should be for seeding your database with some default value. By default, you have an example script in the seed.rb file and you can use that as a reference to setup the structure you want.

However you will only want to use this option, if all you want is test/dummy data to play with alas, your use case may be different. But if you do require this data all for the sake of testing, I will recommend you follow a TDD approach. Hope this helps you.